# Swift array of UIView subclasses conforming to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift3, protocols

What is the best way to mirror Obj-C’s `@property (nonatomic) NSArray <SomeProtocol>* items;` where the items are `UIView` subclasses?

In the example below, I'd like to store an array of `UIKit` components (e.g. `UILabel`, `UIButton`, etc) that all conform to a protocol, however this gives an error `Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

What are some alternative ways of modeling this?

Example playground:

```
import UIKit

/// Protocol representing a form field model
protocol FieldRepresentable {}

/// Protocol representing a form UI control
protocol FormControllable {
    associatedtype FieldRepresentable

    init(model: FieldRepresentable)

    var model: FieldRepresentable { get }
}

/// Example label model
class FormLabelElement: FieldRepresentable {}

/// Example label UI control
class FormLabel: UILabel, FormControllable {

    required init(model: FormLabelElement) {
        self.model = model

        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    let model: FormLabelElement

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
}

/// Example form
class Form: UIView {

    // Error here
    var fields: [FormControllable]?

}
```

Comment: Perhaps this article could be of some help: https://milen.me/writings/swift-generic-protocols/

Comment: You need to declare your protocol as `:class` to indicate that it will only ever apply to class objects, not structs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nate Cook suggested

> One simple-ish way to approach that would be to remove the associated type from `FormControllable` and make its `init` failable. Each conforming type would basically have to validate that it knows what to do with the specific `FieldRepresentable` type passed. I think you'd lose a little bit of type safety/expression but would gain the ability to have a non-uniform array

so the final version for that approach ended up being:

```
import UIKit

/// Protocol representing a form field model that is used to instantiate a UI control
protocol FieldRepresentable: class {}

/// Protocol representing a form UI control
protocol FormControllable: class {
    init?(model: FieldRepresentable)
}

/// Example label model
class FormLabelElement: FieldRepresentable {}

/// Example label UI control
class FormLabel: UILabel, FormControllable {

    required init?(model: FieldRepresentable) {
        guard let model = model as? FormLabelElement else { return nil }
        self.model = model

        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    let model: FormLabelElement

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
}

/// Example form
class Form: UIView {
    var fields = [FormControllable]()
}

// Create a form
let form = Form()
let labelModel = FormLabelElement()
let labelField = FormLabel(model: labelModel)!
form.fields.append(labelField)
print(form.fields)

form.fields.forEach { (field) in
    if field is FormLabel {
        print("We have a label field")
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if your model protocol is generic enough, Soroush suggested

> One idea is to make your field representable type into an enum, since theres a set number of types of form field elements
>
> Then you just need a big switch that turns an enum into a form element
>
> And you can take an array of field data cases and map them into an array of form elements